The edge graph of an edge graph
There is a graph A. To find out if there is a graph B whose edge graph is A, you need to find out if one of the graphs of a certain set is a minor of graph B. And what needs to be done in order to find out if there is a graph C whose edge graph is B and whose edge graph is A.

not a minor, but a generated subgraph


Is there a question here? If so, it is not clear what it is.
